# Azure Bot Framework custom state cosmosdb data is null

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to store conversations and state of Bot framework in Cosmos DB.
I followed the documentation here-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb
After following the steps, the object is created in cosmosdb but the data property object is null.
[image: CosmosDB data property is null Image]

Thanks,
Mitesh

Comment: This looks like a UserData record (based on the id field).  Are you storing something in UserData?  If you aren't specifically storing anything in UserData, then the data field will be empty (as you've shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Azure Cosmos DB to store and manage bot’s state data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb) is working for me, if I store data in UserData or ConversationData, I can view the data via **Data Explorer** on Azure Cosmos DB portal. As Eric Dahlvang mentioned in his comment, please check if you store some data in your code logic. Or you can put my code snippet in your bot app and test if it works for you.

**Store state data:**

```
context.UserData.SetValue("mytestdata", activity.Text.ToString());
```

or

```
context.ConversationData.SetValue("mytestcdata", "this is test Conversation Data");
```

**View the state data:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @FeiHan. This works..! and I am able to save the data now. The actual thing i wanted was saving conversation history, but realized later that it is for storing state of the conversation. After doing some research I found that it can be done using middleware logging. - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-Middleware